# Tkinter: how to have a button trigger such that it affects another button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a GUI that is meant to emulate an online shop of some sort.

One part of the task is to have a button that will generate a HTML document with images of the user's chosen product category.

Below I have provided my four radio buttons along with their IntVar and commands.

Each of the RadioButton commands do the same thing but extract information from different websites, so for brevity I have only provided the command for the slipper category.

```
home_hobbies = Tk()

status = IntVar()

def show_slippers():
    #open downloaded file to extract info
    slipperfile = open('slippers.html','r',encoding = 'utf-8').read()
    prices = findall("<span.*value'>(.*)</span>", slipperfile) #regex prices
    titles = findall('<h3.*body ">\n\s*(.*)', slipperfile) #regex titles
    select_categ.config(state=NORMAL) #make the text box edit-able
    select_categ.delete(1.0, END) #delete any text already in the text box
    #for loop to find first five items and print them
    for i in range(5):
        title = titles[i]
        price = prices[i]
        result = str(i+1) + ". " + title + ' - $' + price + "\n"
        select_categ.insert(END, result) #write list of products
    select_categ.config(state=DISABLED) #make sure the user can't edit the text box

slippers = Radiobutton(home_hobbies, command = show_slippers, indicator = 'off', variable = status, value = 1, text = 'Winter Slippers')
diy = Radiobutton(home_hobbies, command = show_diy, indicator = 'off', variable = status, value = 2, text = "DIY Supplies")
#newstock radiobuttons
sports = Radiobutton(home_hobbies, command = show_sports, indicator = 'off', variable = status, value = 3, text = "Pool Toys")
novelties = Radiobutton(home_hobbies, command = show_novelties, indicator = 'off', variable = status, value = 4, text = "Novelty Items")

select_categ = Text(home_hobbies, wrap = WORD, font = content_font, bg = widgetbg, fg = fontcolour, width = 40)
```

Above, I also provided the line of code that generates the Text widget as it may help in answering my question (I don't have a very deep understanding of this widget despite reading the effbot page about 20 times over).

I now have a different button whose task is to generate a HTML doc with it's own command, "show_img":

```
htmlshow = Button(home_hobbies, text = "View Product Images", command = show_img)
```

I am trying to make the show_img() command work such that I have a preamble of HTML coding, and then, depending on which radibutton has been chosen, the function will replace sections of the code with the corresponding information:

```
def show_img():
#in this section I write my HTML code which includes replaceable sections such as "image1" and source_url
    if slipper_trig:
        table = table.replace("source_url", '<a href = "https://www.etsy.com/au/search?q=slippers"> Etsy - Shop Unique Gifts for Everyone</a>')
        imgfile = open('slippers.html', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8').read()
        images = findall('<img\n*.*image\n*\s*src="(.*)"', imgfile)
        for i in range(5):
            image = images[i]
            table = table.replace("image"+str(i+1), image)
```

I tried to add BooleanVar into the commands for my Radio Buttons like this:

```
slipper_trig = False
diy_trig = False
pool_trig = False
novelty_trig = False

#Function for the product category buttons

#
def show_slippers():
    #make selected category true and change all others to false
    slipper_trig = True
    diy_trig = False
    pool_trig = False
    novelty_trig = False
```

As a way to distinguish between the categories but the GUI clearly doesn't remember the value of "slipper_trig" after its been defined as true in the "show_slippers" function.

Maybe I need to try and integrate the "show_img" command into my original functions that define the RadioButtons? Maybe I should be figuring out how to determine the category chosen by what's shown in the text box?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have `Button(..., command=function_name)` to run `function_name()` after clicking button ? How do you define `RadionButtons` ? Your question without minimal working code is useless. We would have to write all code from scratch to show how do it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my question. Not sure how to tag you in this comment so I hope you see it. This was my first question so I hope to get better with practice :)

Comment: Your `show_slippers()` function is uselessly setting a bunch of local variables, that will vanish at the end of the function.  They are *utterly unrelated* to the global variables with the same names.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show minimal working code with your problem so I can only show some minimal example with `Button` and `RadioButton` to show how to use these widgets.

I don't know if you used `command=function_name` in `Button`.
BTW: it has to be function's name without `()`

I don't know if you used `.get()` to get value from `StringVar`/`Intvar`/`BooleanVar` assigned to `RadioButtons`.

**EDIT** I added `Checkbutton` because probably you may need it instead of `Radiobutton`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    selected = result_var.get()

    print('selected:', selected)

    if selected == 'hello':
        print("add HELLO to html")
    elif selected == 'bye':
        print("add BYE to html")
    else:
        print("???")

    print('option1:', option1_var.get())  # 1 or 0 if you use IntVar
    print('option2:', option2_var.get())  # 1 or 0 if you use IntVar

    if option1_var.get() == 1:
        print("add OPTION 1 to html")

    if option2_var.get() == 1:
        print("add OPTION 2 to html")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

result_var = tk.StringVar(root, value='hello')
rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Hello World", variable=result_var, value='hello')
rb1.pack()
rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Good Bye", variable=result_var, value='bye')
rb2.pack()

option1_var = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)
opt1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Option 1', variable=option1_var)
opt1.pack()

option2_var = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)
opt2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Option 2', variable=option2_var)
opt2.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Doc on [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/): [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), [Radiobutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm), [Checkbutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)